# What size scaffolding wooden planks should I use

Tags: safety, construction, masonry, lumber

I'm erecting scaffolding with 5'x5' frames and 7' crossbraces. I want to use wooden planks.  OSHA planks apparently are 2" x 10" x 8' Southern Yellow Pine and cost about $30-$40.  At the hardware store, I can get the same size board for about $10.  My question is, Are OSHA planks somehow different, or can I just use the boards from the hardware store?

Comment: Are you renting the scaffolding or are you constructing this yourself? What materials are used for the frame?  Is it at a worksite or just to do some home repair? Southern Yellow Pine is a very strong hard pine.  What are the boards that you say you can buy?  Is this inside or outside?  Will it remain in place for a long period of time?  There are a lot of unanswered questions here that can have a determining effect on an answer.

Comment: @RMDman I'm constructing this myself out of steel frame for my house outside and will be the only person working on it.  The job should take a couple of weeks. So, I'm not concerned about violating OSHA, rather, if the boards from the hardware store, which are also Southern Yellow Pine, will offer the same support as the OSHA ones.

Comment: If we don't know what species of wood the boards are made it's impossible to determine.

Comment: Further, I for one don't want to recommend something that could be a problem in the future because of weather, wear and tear, etc.

Comment: Most wood is also graded.  Two planks of the same wood are graded differently due different factors.  If possible I would try the two different pieces to see the difference.  Remember you are going to be standing on only an inch and a half of wood.  10 dollar planks might have enough defects to make it fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The price differential is probably 80-90% insurance for the maker, and perhaps also a bit of high-grading.

The "same boards at the lumberyard" are probably #2 - the "OSHA boards" *may* be #1 or Select Structural grade, and that will cost more than #2 at the lumberyard, too - if they even stock it.

If you are walking off the OSHA-approved zone, you can do a lot better for scaffold platforms by not limiting it to just the 1-1/2" of lumber thickness. They require inspection by you to verify that each is in usable condition, and has not degraded, as you are the person who will be injured if they fail, which is the tradeoff you take when deciding to walk off and be responsible for your own.

I built a Structural Insulated Panel house, and the panel scraps made the nicest, solidest (while still being light enough to handle) "staging planks" I've ever used. If you can find some of those panels without too much hassle, might be worth a look.

I also have a set of "personally picked through by me" 6 foot (for my staging) planks cut from 12 foot 2x8's. Things like "degradation from weather" mean that I reject some from continuing in that use from time to time, and grade quality defects meant that some never were approved for that use by me in the first place.

If you want to "upgrade" those, with your 8 foot planks for your 7 foot span (assuming your staging is of the "boards overhang" flavor - mine is "boards set in" so there's no loose ends to step out on and regret), buy 14 foot 2x4's (or twice as many 8 footers, if you can find 8-footers that aren't junk and don't mind the offcuts) and screw half of one to the bottom of the 2x8, narrow edge of the 2x4 to the face of the 2x8 as a wide-topped T shape - or place one on either side, making your whole assembly ~ 10+ inches wide in a "C-Channel" shape. Reinforcing with steel is another option. Those will also keep the planks from being kicked off the support in a "boards overhang" setup.

Comment: On C-Channel: It might be better to screw the 2x4 to the _top_ of the board, so when (not if) you drop a tool on the board, it stays there, rather than bouncing over the edge.  This does mean you lose the "stop the boards being kicked off the support" function.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica, that would make a very dangerous walking surface. Have you every tried walking around in a trough? If your feet can't overhang at least a little for balance everything gets much more difficult. It's essentially a full-length, double-sided trip hazard. Nice thought, but no.

Answer (score 6):

I simply don't like using single planks for scaffolding. If they aren't carefully selected, a flaw can result in a quick, unpleasant ride through the atmosphere. They also tend to be very *bouncy*, which doesn't promote confidence or quality work.

Instead, use **2x4 ladder frames topped with 1/2" plywood or OSB**. No need for large lumber at all. My father built a set of these about 16" wide for his 7-8' scaffolding when probably 30 years ago, and while I'd have replaced them by now they're still in use. They were used regularly on construction sites for decades. They're much more rigid than flat lumber, and they won't drop you (at least not as abruptly) if one board cracks.